# Which embedded database to use for file indexing applications

Tags: python, database, indexing, filesystems, embedded-database

I need to develop a file indexing application in python and wanted to know which embedded database is the best one to use for indexing.

Any help on this topic is appreciated.
Thanks,

Rajesh

Comment: @Rajesh could you elaborate more. What type of data? What kid of operations to be done on data?

Comment: Basically i will be preparing a script to index only local files and want to store the full text and keywords into a db - similar like Google Desktop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use sqlite :

- http://www.sqlite.org/
- https://github.com/ghaering/pysqlite

Another one that you could explore is

- http://www.equi4.com/metakit/

For file indexing there are tools like pylucene, xapian.

- [Python file indexing and searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532312/python-file-indexing-and-searching)

Other relevant link on SO

- [File indexing (using Binary trees?) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110843/file-indexing-using-binary-trees-in-python)

Comment: Can you please guide me which is more suitable for Python?

Comment: @Rajesh Vaya : I would suggest that you use xapian written in c/c++ and has python binding. Please see my edited link for other tools like pylucene and whoosh. Xapian and woosh are quite capable for your job.

Comment: sqlite is built in to python. you could give that a shot and if for some reason it didn't meet your needs move your data to another database. one of the few criticisms of sqlite to be aware of is its support of concurrent access.

Comment: @Adam, @Pyfunc: Thanks a lot for the instant reply

Comment: @Rajesh: you're most welcome. In addition to accepting the answer, as you've done, you can also click the upward arrow to give pyfunc some points if you feel that his/her answer was useful :-)

Comment: It says vote up requires 15 reputation.. i guess i don't have that much since i am a new user.

Comment: One more question.. which DB is used by Whoosh?

Comment: @RajeshVaya I am late here, but Whoosh uses files and directories to store its indexes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955410/where-does-whoosh-python-physically-store-the-indexed-content

Answer (score 0):

You can also check [Firebird](http://www.firebirdnews.org/docs/fb2min.html) who    have for good drivers for [Python](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=devel&sub=python)
You can also use the [sphinx](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=files&id=sphinx) add    in
Or you can also use [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) and firebird like [infovark](http://www.infovark.com/)