# Where does Whoosh (Python) physically store the indexed content?

Tags: python, indexing, whoosh

I am beginning to research on content indexing implementation, and was having a look at Whoosh (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Whoosh/).

I am curious to know where Whoosh stores its content physically - Is it using files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whoosh uses a [pluggable storage system](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/filedb/filestore.html#whoosh.filedb.filestore.Storage); if you use the [`create_in()` function](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html#whoosh.index.create_in) then a [`FileStorage()` class](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/filedb/filestore.html#whoosh.filedb.filestore.FileStorage) is used that stores indexes in files in a directory.

See the [Whoosh quickstart](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html):

> Once you have the schema, you can create an index using the `create_in` function:
>
> ```
> import os.path
> from whoosh.index import create_in
>
> if not os.path.exists("index"):
>     os.mkdir("index")
> ix = create_in("index", schema)
> ```
>
> (At a low level, this creates a `Storage` object to contain the index. A `Storage` object represents that medium in which the index will be stored. Usually this will be `FileStorage`, which stores the index as a set of files in a directory.)